# Alt Beacon Library, RegionBootstrap and BeaconManager working simultaneously

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon

I have a background scanning for beacon which I have included in my Application class as mentioned in the [sample code](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html).

Below is my code for clarity :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
        .getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static MyApplication mInstance;
private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
public RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
private BroadcastReceiver br;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser(). setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(mInstance);
    //beaconManager.setDebug(true);
    //beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000); //Background Scanning rate frequency

    //initRegions(getApplicationContext());


}
........
public void initRegions(Context context)
{


    System.out.println("Inside initRegions");
    ArrayList<BeaconClass> b_a = ind_constants.getPOIList(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        if (b_a.size() > 0) {
            List<Region> list_region = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < b_a.size(); i++) {
                Beacon b = new Beacon.Builder().setId1(b_a.get(i).id1).setId2(b_a.get(i).id2).setId3(b_a.get(i).id3).build();
                Region region = new Region("Region " + b.getId1(), b.getId1(), b.getId2(), b.getId3());
                list_region.add(region);
                System.out.println("Region added. " + b.getId1());
            }
            System.out.println("A");
            regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(mInstance, list_region);
            System.out.println("B");

        }
        Log.d("in", "Initialized the regions as per the POI List");
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        Log.d("in","Region has not been initialized yet.");
    }
}
.......
public void disableBackgroundMonitoring()
{
    if(regionBootstrap != null) {
        regionBootstrap.disable();
        regionBootstrap = null;
    }
}

public void disableBackgroundMonitoring()
{
    if(regionBootstrap != null) {
        regionBootstrap.disable();
        regionBootstrap = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d("in", "Got a didEnterRegion call for "+region.getUniqueId());
    //Send trigger
}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d("in", "Got a ExitRegion call for "+region.getUniqueId());
    //EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new TriggerEvent(0,"Exited the region "+region.getUniqueId(),false));
    //Send Trigger
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int l, Region region) {
    Log.d("in", "didDetermineStateForRegion "+region.getUniqueId()+" state is : "+l);

}
```

Now once I receive the trigger from `RegionBootstrap`, I start a service which has basically ranging. Below is an excerpt of the service where I init the ranging with the notification so that it can do constant scanning.

```
public ble_scanner(Context context) {
        System.out.println("Inside bleScan init");
        if(init(context))
        {
            beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(context);
            beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser(). setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
            /*--------------------*/

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                    builder.setContentTitle("Scanning for Beacons Oreo");
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(this,B.this);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
                    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);*/

                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Notification Channel ID",
                            "My Notification Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                    channel.setDescription("My Notification Channel Description");
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                    builder.setChannelId(channel.getId());
                    System.out.println("inside new part for 8");

                    System.out.println("PPP : "+beaconManager.isAnyConsumerBound());
                    {
                        beaconManager.unbind(B.this);
                        MyApplication.getInstance().disableBackgroundMonitoring();
                        System.out.println("Unbinded and checking again.");
                        System.out.println(beaconManager.isAnyConsumerBound());

                    }
                    beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 400); //I get the consumer is already bound error here
                    beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
                    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000);
                    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1500);
                    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000); //Ranging mode scan frequency
                    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1500);
                    beaconManager.bind(B.this);
                }
                else{

                    System.out.println("PPP : "+beaconManager.isAnyConsumerBound());
                    {
                        /*beaconManager.unbind(B.this);
                        MyApplication.getInstance().regionBootstrap.disable();
                        System.out.println("Unbinded and checking again.");
                        System.out.println(beaconManager.isAnyConsumerBound());*/

                    }

                    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000); 
                    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(1500);
                    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(5000); //Ranging mode scan frequency
                    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1500);
                    beaconManager.bind(B.this);


                }
            /*--------------------*/

        }
        else
        {
            //init returned false
            Log.d(Tag,"Init returned false");
        }
    }
```

Let's call the RegionBootstrap as `background scanning` and the service as `ranging`. Now the issues :

a) If I initialize the RegionBootstrap and the after getting a trigger from `didEnterRegion` or `didExitRegion`, I start the ranging service , it doesn't start i.e. I get an error stating the `consumer is already bound`. Basically either `background scanning` will work or `ranging`. I am not sure if this is the intended case.

b) As seen in the code, before binding, the `beaconManageer`, I do a check and disable the `background scanning` and `unbind` the service `beaconManageer`. This works for the first time, but then after I stop the service where I call below function.

```
public void stopBLEScan(Context context)
    {
        try {
            beaconManager.unbind(B.this);
            Log.d(Tag,"BLE Scan has been disabled.");
            beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        h.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
```

Now after stopping the BleScan, if I reinit 
`MyApplication.getInstance().initRegions(getApplicationContext());`, it creates a notification in the android device, although the service, where I set up the notification builder, has never been called. Basically, I get below message in logcat after I reinit the `background scanning`.

```
I/BeaconManager: Starting foreground beacon scanning service.
```

c) Now even after I get the notification, if I start the `ranging` service, sometime I get "consumer is already bound".

If I am right, I think, `RegionBootstrap` and `ranging` can work simultaneously.

Basically the sequence to be followed is `start background scanning` **->** `stop background scanning` **->** `start ranging` **->** `stop ranging` **->** `start background scanning`

**Side question** :  In `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` when am ranging the beacons, I have to add below code :

```
beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers();
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);

    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
```

else beacons are not detected. Am confused as to why we need to add this? Even if we have to, how many times? In your reference application, you have done this twice. How to determine as to how many time we got to do that?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`RegionBootstrap` is a convenience class designed to be put in a custom Android `Application` class to set up beacon monitoring in the background such that it will relaunch your app.  It is designed to be set up once in an `Application#onCreate` method, and left alone.  It is not designed to be re-initialized at a later time.

If you want to dynamically start and stop monitoring I suggest you do not use `RegionBootstrap` outside its designed use.

Instead, call `beaconManager.bind(...)` then in the `onBeaconServiceConnected` callback, call `beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(...)`.  You can stop monitoring later with `beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(...)`, and then you can unbind (if desired) with `beaconManger.unbind(...)`.  In the calls to bind and unbind you will need to pass a `BeaconConsumer`.  Calls to bind/unbind must be matched otherwise you will get error messages.

Comment: So if I have `RegionBootstrap` in my Application Class, then I can't start Ranging in Android 8+ ?

Comment: You can range and monitor regions at the same time yes.  In fact, the reference application shows exactly how you can do this.  But you don't need to stop monitoring in order to start ranging (you can leave monitoring on).  And if you do want to stop monitoring for some reason, just don't use `RegionBootstrap` and instead use `beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(...)` / `beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(...)`

Comment: As I speak, am trying the `startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion` thing, but I have a question. Why is that am getting teh "consumer is already bound" error when am trying to bind a `beaconconsumer` while the `RegionBootstrap` is still running in above case.

Comment: It's very difficult to debug larger programs on StackOverflow -- the question contains 175 lines of code.  I'd suggest  trying to create a smaller minimalist sample that reproduces the problem.  Ideally in 40 lines or fewer.